# QMake, SVN получить строку ревизии

Tags: c++, windows, qt, svn, qmake

У меня есть 2 способа получить ревизию SVN:

```
DEFINES += SVN_REVISION1=\\\"$$system(svnversion -n)\\\"
DEFINES += SVN_REVISION2=$$system(svnversion -n $$PWD)
```

Оба способа рабочие. В первой выдается версия как строка. Во второй после манипуляциями с дефайнами:

```
#define VALUE_TO_STRING(x) #x
#define VALUE(x) VALUE_TO_STRING(x)
#define SVN_REVISION_STR VALUE(SVN_REVISION)
```

тоже превращается в строку.
И эти 2 способа уходят в отказ, если скопировать проект в папку без SVN.
Запуск программы `svnversion -n` выдает 2 слова: `Unversioned directory`. Как не уходить в отказ хотя бы по одному способу? Как проверить нахождение в репозитории?

---

Упрощаю пример:

```
AA = \\\"Unversioned directory\\\"
BB = \\\"212M\\\"
message($$AA)
message($$BB)
```

Вывод:

```
Project MESSAGE: \"Unversioned directory\"
Project MESSAGE: \"212M\"
```

Как тут избавить от пробела, или обнаружить пробел, или оставить только первое слово?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение сделал такое:

```
AA = $$system(svnversion -n)

equals(AA, "Unversioned directory") {
    DEFINES += SVN_REVISION=\\\"noSVN\\\"
} else {
    DEFINES += SVN_REVISION=\\\"$$AA\\\"
}
```